# Can't find the right path for "background-image: url()" on xampp localhost

Tags: css, path, xampp, localhost

```
png file location: xampp/htdocs/project/images/icons.png;
css file location: xampp/htdocs/project/resources/style.css;
html file location: xampp/htdocs/project/index.html;
```

While the path `background-image: url(/images/icons.png)` worked on live server, on local host it doesnt. Looking forward for your answer :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because the image is in another directory, I would suggest putting the exact path of the image.

```
background-image: url(../images/icons.png);
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, well the one above is the exact path of the image

Comment: show me the URL of the localhost

Comment: There you go: https://imgur.com/a/tjztOiQ , hope you'll figure it out :D.

Comment: Btw a little hint: in index.html file i switched the path of images sources from src="/resources/icon-menu.svg" (on live version via visual studio ) to src="/google_homepage/resources/icon-menu.svg" (on local host) in order to work, even though maybe there s a different story with url paths since they must be relative to css file (if im not wrong) .

Comment: forgot the url: http://localhost/google_homepage/resources/icons.png

Comment: you can just add the exact path of the file or copy it directly from the upper navigation bar inside the directory

Comment: like for your situation the URL is:  C:\xampp\htdocs\google_homepage\images\icons.png

Comment: and if your CSS file is inside htdocs, you'll just have to add the directory as you did before without the slash forward  : "google_homepage/resources/icon-menu.svg"

Comment: this is the one that worked : /google_homepage/images/icons.png, and I think it worked previously but the css didnt update because google cached and I opened a new icognito tab and it worked. Thanks !

Comment: mark the problem as solved